# Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I know you can do this easily with Newtonsoft. As I am working with .NET Core 3.0, however, I am trying to use the new methods for interacting with JSON files —i.e., `System.Text.Json`—and I refuse to believe that what I am trying to do is all that difficult!

My application needs to list users that have not already been added to my database. In order to get the full list of all users, the app retrieves a JSON string from a web API. I now need to cycle through each of these users and check if they have already been added to my application before returning a new JSON list to my view so that it can display the new potential users to the end user.

As I am ultimately returning another JSON at the end of the process, I don't especially want to bother deserializing it to a model. Note that the structure of data from the API *could* change, but it will *always* have a key from which I can compare to my database records.

My code currently looks like this:

```cs
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var rawJsonDownload = wc.DownloadString("WEB API CALL");
    var users =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<UserObject>>(rawJsonDownload);

    foreach (var user in users.ToList())
    {
        //Check if User is new
        if (CHECKS)
        {
            users.Remove(user);
        }
    }

    return Json(users); 
}
```

This seems like a *lot* of hoops to jump through in order to achieve something that would be fairly trivial with Newtonsoft.

Can anyone advise me on a better way of doing this—and, ideally, without the need for the `UserObject`?

Comment: "_…something that I believe would be fairly trivial with Newtonsoft_" - if you're doing this as a learning exercise why not create a Newtonsoft solution first and then reverse-engineer your .Net solution based on that. As far as I can tell, the above code is about as trivial as you can get for this sort of thing - your check against the db relies on a value from the source and removing a node requires a code-step no matter what framework you use.

Comment: This is probably not your point, but you can reduce your code by using the RemoveAll method on List. This will reduce your solution to 3 lines of code (deserialize, remove, serialize). It doesn't get much shorter than that. If this is not what you're looking for, maybe you could give an example implementation using newtonsoft of what you are trying to accomplish using system.text.json

Comment: Since you are using `System.Text.Json` you might consider ditching `WebClient` for `HttpClient` and doing async deserialization.  See e.g. https://stu.dev/a-look-at-jsondocument/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your problem is that you would like to retrieve, filter, and pass along some JSON without needing to define a complete data model for that JSON.  With Json.NET, you could use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for this purpose.  Your question is, **can this currently be solved as easily with `System.Text.Json`?**

As of .NET 6, this cannot be done quite as easily with `System.Text.Json` because it has no support for [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) which is often quite convenient in such applications.  There is currently an open issue *[Add JsonPath support to JsonDocument/JsonElement #41537](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41537)* tracking this.

That being said, imagine you have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name 1",
    "address": {
      "Line1": "line 1",
      "Line2": "line 2"
    },
    // More properties omitted
  }
  //, Other array entries omitted
]
```

And some `Predicate<long> shouldSkip` filter method indicating whether an entry with a specific `id` should not be returned, corresponding to `CHECKS` in your question.  What are your options?

**In .NET 6 and later you could parse your JSON to a [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0), edit its contents, and return the modified JSON.**  A `JsonNode` represents an [editable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#create-a-jsonnode-dom-with-object-initializers-and-make-changes) JSON Document Object Model and thus most closely corresponds to Newtonsoft's [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy.

The following code shows an example of this:

```
var root = JsonNode.Parse(rawJsonDownload).AsArray(); // AsArray() throws if the root node is not an array.
for (int i = root.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (shouldSkip(root[i].AsObject()["id"].GetValue<long>()))
        root.RemoveAt(i);
}

return Json(root);
```

Mockup fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HGRDeT)

**In .NET Core 3.x and later, you could parse to a [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument) and return some filtered set of [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) nodes**.  This works well if the filtering logic is very simple and you don't need to modify the JSON in any other way.  But do note the following limitations of `JsonDocument`:

- `JsonDocument` and `JsonElement` are read-only.  They can be used only to *examine* JSON values, not to modify or create JSON values.
- `JsonDocument` is disposable, and in fact must needs be disposed to *minimize the impact of the garbage collector (GC) in high-usage scenarios*, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0#remarks).  In order to return a `JsonElement` you must [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.clone?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_Clone) it.

The filtering scenario in the question is simple enough that the following code can be used:

```
using var usersDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(rawJsonDownload);
var users = usersDocument.RootElement.EnumerateArray()
    .Where(e => !shouldSkip(e.GetProperty("id").GetInt64()))
    .Select(e => e.Clone())
    .ToList();

return Json(users);
```

Mockup fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rO10rE).

**In any version, you could create a *partial* data model that deserializes only the properties you need for filtering, with the remaining JSON bound to a [`[JsonExtensionDataAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute) property.**  This should allow you to implement the necessary filtering without needing to hardcode an entire data model.

To do this, define the following model:

```
public class UserObject
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionDataAttribute]
    public IDictionary<string, object> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize and filter as follows:

```
var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<UserObject>>(rawJsonDownload);
users.RemoveAll(u => shouldSkip(u.Id));

return Json(users);
```

This approach ensures that properties relevant to filtering can be deserialized appropriately without needing to make any assumptions about the remainder of the JSON.  While this isn't as quite easy as using LINQ to JSON, the total code complexity is bounded by the complexity of the filtering checks, not the complexity of the JSON.  And in fact my opinion is that this approach is, in practice, a little easier to work with than the `JsonDocument` approach because it makes it somewhat easier to inject modifications to the JSON if required later.

Mockup fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eDvr7K).

**No matter which you choose**, you might consider ditching `WebClient` for [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.0) and using `async` deserialization.  E.g.:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(); // Cache statically and reuse in production
var root = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<JsonArray>("WEB API CALL");
```

Or

```
using var usersDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("WEB API CALL"));
```

Or

```
var users = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<UserObject>>(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("WEB API CALL"));
```

You would need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453278/3744182) your API method to be `async` as well.

Comment: Wow an extremely in depth and well explained answer :) thank you!

Comment: one of the best answers all the times

Comment: This is the best answer. I am having issues with inserting property at specified location, so wondering if you could help with the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140014/adding-a-property-into-specified-location-into-json-using-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: Update: there is now [support for JSON Path](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything).

Comment: is available since .Net 6 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: thank you for the amazing answer :)

Comment: @elena - answer updated.