# dynamically remove property from JSON using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.text.json

**Note 1 :** I do **NOT** want to use **newtonsoft.json** !

**Note 2 :** This is not a duplicate, other answers use **newtonsoft.json** !

Note 3 : using `.Net` 5.

How do I remove a property from a Json string with `System.Text.Json` ?

```
{
 Name: "Mike",
 Age : 12,
 Location : "Africa"
}
```

I want to be able to remove based on both property name and value. For example remove Age property or remove persons with the name Mike.

Comment: Why do you have _"using Json.Net"_ in the title if you want to use `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Why don't use want to use `newtonsoft.json` but tag it?

Comment: _"How do I remove a property from a Json string with System.Text.Json ?"_  - by updating to .NET 6 and using new `JsonNode` API

Comment: @GuruStron sorry I thought both are the same. I want to use System.Text.Json

Comment: @GuruStron Sorry I can not update to 6 . But if there is no way with 5 please provide an answer

Comment: You can make those additional properties go into an `extension data` property, without losing on roundtrip, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow

Comment: You could store it as a `Dictionary<string, object>` then simply remove the `Age` key

Comment: Your json is not valid. Post a valid json at first. "from a Json string with System.Text.Json" - what do you mean? Json object or just string? You can use using string.replace for a string. You don't need any serializer for this.

Comment: `JsonDocument` is read-only.  Assuming you don't know your JSON structure in advance and can't deserialize to some typed data model, see [Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58997718/3744182) for options and workarounds.

Comment: @Serge There are obviously many ways to transform JSON. Unless you have a trivial use case, string manipulation is potentially error-prone. It is almost always better to deserialize, process, and serialize again.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht What I meant that json is not valid since it has c# tag and can not be a javascript object

Answer (score 3):

I hope the below solution might help to remove the property.
emp is your object

```
var jsonObject = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(emp.ToJson()).AsObject();
```

Remove the property
Age is the property of emp

```
jsonObject.Remove(nameof(emp.Age));
```