# C# How to change a single value in a dynamic json object with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```json
{
   "a":{
      "lot":"of",
      "random":"stuff"
   },
   "url":"https://a.url.I.want.to.change",
   "some":{
      "other":"very",
      "random":"stuff"
   }
}
```

I read that json from a file and I want to change exactly the `url` field and than I want to save it back to the file.
I am using `System.Text.Json` in the entire project and I don´t want to introduce a dependency to `newtonsoft.json`

I tried it using `dynamic` like this:

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
dynamic settings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

settings.url = "https://my.new.url";   // <- that is the problem

File.WriteAllText(filepath, JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings));
```

and also like this:

```cs
settings["url"] = "https://my.new.url";
```

but none of the approaches work because `JsonSerializer` deserializes it into an `JsonElement`, which is readonly I think.

Has anyone an idea of how that could be solved?

Comment: Are you using .NET 6?  Then easiest way is to deserialize to `JsonNode` as shown in e.g. [Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001666/3744182).

Comment: Yes I´m using .NET6.
Thank you! That is exactly what I needed! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    string json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

    var settings  = JsonNode.Parse(json); 
    settings ["url"]= "new url";
    json=settings.ToJsonString(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

    File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
```